# Cognos Substr with varying lengths

Tags: report, substring, cognos

I have an ID field that is just numbers but the ID's vary in length. If the number is 16 characters long then I need to display 'x' + last 4 of the ID, if not then just display the last 10 of the ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your ID field is already a string:

```
CASE character_length([ID]) 
WHEN 16 THEN 'x' || substring([ID],character_length([ID]) - 3) 
ELSE substring([ID],character_length([ID]) - 9) 
END
```

If your ID is stored as an integer, I'd recommend creating a new data item that casts it as a varchar (say named 'ID String'):

```
CAST([ID],VARCHAR(16))
```

Then substitute the new value in the first expression:

```
CASE character_length([ID String]) 
WHEN 16 THEN 'x' || substring([ID String],character_length([ID String]) - 3) 
ELSE substring([ID String],character_length([ID String]) - 9) 
END
```